# How set Two values in one Name with UriTemplate?

Tags: c#, wcf

I created this code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "detect?v=1.0&q={q}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
DetectLanguage GetDetectLanguage(string q);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "translate?v=1.0&q={query}&(langpair={from}|{to})", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
TranslateLanguage GetTranslateLanguage(string query, string from, string to);
```

But I get this error:

> The UriTemplate
>   `'translate?v=1.0&q={query}&(langpair={from}|{to})'` is not valid; each portion of the
>   query string must be of the form
>   `'name=value'`, when value cannot be a
>   compound segment. See the
>   documentation for UriTemplate for more
>   details.

I know `(name=value)`. How do I get `Name={value1}|{value2}`? Is it possible?

Or any other solution!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message explains, you cannot have `langpair={from}|{to}` because that would apparently be a compounded value.

You can use the form

`langpair={langpair}`

and then use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) in your method to get the two parts:

```
string langpair = "en|fr";
string[] parts = langpair.Split('|');
string from = parts[0];  // "en"
string to = parts[1];    // "fr"
```